# What is the error for the estimate of the probability of a binomial distribution?

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, parameter-estimation

I want to estimate the probability $p$ of a Binomial distribution $B(n,p)$. I draw $n$ samples and get $s$ successes. The estimate for $p$ is $$\hat{p} = s/n.$$ What is the variance of $\hat{p}$?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: I do have a program which produces a sample of some parametrised distribution and (exactly) calculates the probability of that sample. I wrote a test that repeatedly samples the distribution with fixed parameters. That gives me an estimate of the real sample probability, which I compare with the calculated sample probability. For this to make sense I need the variance on the estimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your definition, $s$ is a random variable, whose mean is $np$ and whose variance is $np(1-p)$ (this follows from the fact that the number of successes is a binomial $\mathcal{B}(n,p)$ random variable).

Thus,

\begin{align}
\text{var}(\hat{p})&=\text{var}\left(\frac{s}{n}\right)\\\
                   &=\frac{1}{n^{2}}\text{var}(s)\\
                   &=\frac{np(1-p)}{n^{2}}\\
                   &=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

When the sample proportion $\hat p$ is used to estimate $\pi$, the standard error is 
$$= \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi (1-\pi)}{n}}$$

Standard error from data

Unfortunately, the standard error of $\hat p$ involves $\pi$, and this is unknown in practical problems. To get a numerical value for the standard error, we must therefore replace $\pi$ with our best estimate of its value, $\hat p$.

**standard error is the calculated using the standard deviation (square root of variance that you asked for)**

$$= \sqrt{\dfrac{\hat p (1-\hat p)}{n}}$$

Good Luck

Comment: Why a downvote, the question is simple as is and there is nothing much to iadd.  I wonder why someone would downvote if not vote up.

Comment: My guess is that you gave a link without making your answer self-contained. if the dies link, this becomes useless. (Besides the subjective reason that this shows very little effort on your side.)

Comment: Understood, I shall type out the answer.